# Vue Testing Library with NaiveUI

Tags: vue.js, testing-library, vitest

I'm using Vue 3, NaiveUI, Vitest + Vue Testing Library and got to the issue with testing component toggle on button click and conditional rendering.

**Component TSample:**

```
<template>
  <n-button role="test" @click="show = !show" text size="large" type="primary">
    <div data-testid="visible" v-if="show">visible</div>
    <div data-testid="hidden" v-else>hidden</div>
  </n-button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'
import { NButton } from 'naive-ui'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'TSample',

  components: {
    NButton
  },

  setup() {
    const show = ref(true)
    return {
      show
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

**The test case I have:**

```
import { render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/vue'
import TSample from './TSample.vue'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'

describe('Tests TSample component', () => {
  it('toggles between visible and hidden text inside the button', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup()
    const { getByText, queryByText, getByRole } = render(TSample)

    expect(getByRole('test')).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(getByText(/visible/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(queryByText('hidden')).not.toBeInTheDocument()

    await user.click(getByRole('test'))
    await waitFor(() => expect(queryByText(/hidden/i)).toBeInTheDocument()) <-- fails
  })
})
```

**The error:**

```
        <transition-stub />
        <span
          class="n-button__content"
        >
          <div
            data-testid="visible"
          >
            visible
          </div>
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>...Error: expect(received).toBeInTheDocument()

received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
```

Moreover in Testing Preview I get:

```
<button
  class="n-button n-button--primary-type n-button--large-type mx-4"
  tabindex="0"
  type="button"
  disabled="false"
  role="test"
>
  <transition-stub>
  </transition-stub><span class="n-button__content">
    <div data-testid="visible">visible</div>
  </span>
</button>
```

a button, which makes it more confusing to me...  Same situation happened when I replaced `waitFor` with `nextTick` from `Vue`, the component didn't do a toggle at all on click.

**What works but isn't acceptable**

When I changed the `n-button` to just `button`, the test passed and divs are toggled, but that's not the goal of this component. The component isn't supposed to be changed.

**What I have tried:**

I tried different approaches with reaching the div that contains `hidden` text. Either it was like above - `queryByText`/`getByText` or `getByTestId`, but test fails at the same point.

Also followed with similar approach shown at [Testing Library - Disappearance Sample](https://github.com/testing-library/vue-testing-library/blob/main/src/__tests__/components/Disappearance.vue)
but doesn't work in my case above.

What actually is going on and how can I test the change on click with such third-party components?

If more info is needed/something is missing, also let me know, I'll update the question.

Any suggestions, explanations - much appreciated.